# where is located FirebaseDynamicLinks?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

With unit I need to add in the import to access FirebaseDynamicLinks ? doc at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/dynamiclinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks didn't say it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're asking which Java package the class is in. While the content of the page you link to indeed doesn't say that, you can derive it by looking at the URL of the page itself:

```
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/dynamiclinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks
```

So the package is:

```
com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks
```